# I need to create an object from a form group, without index

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to transform this object:

```json
{
    "id": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "tst",
        "data": {
            "CompanyName": "",
            "Size": "2"
        }
    },
    "id": {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "tstst",
        "data": {
            "CompanyName1": "",
            "": "100"
        }
    }
}
```

Into this: (without the id)?

```json
{
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "tst",
        "data": {
            "CompanyName": "",
            "Size": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "tstst",
        "data": {
            "CompanyName1": "",
            "": "100"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A javascript object can't have duplicate keys, 1st above has `id` as a key twice

Comment: Should your expected result be an array instead of an object?

Comment: I need this to be on an object to stringify

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Array will help you.

```
[
  {data: ''},
  {data: ''},
]
```